How to test if a BigDecimal object is divisible by another BigDecimal in Java?
I'm working on a problem from a Java textbook which asks to find the first 10 numbers with 50 decimal digits that are divisible by 2 or 3. Here is my code:
import java.math.*;

public class Divisible {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal numbers = new BigDecimal("0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        BigDecimal number2 = new BigDecimal("2.0");
        BigDecimal number3 = new BigDecimal("3.0");
        BigDecimal increment = new BigDecimal("0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001");
        int count = 0;

        while (count < 10) {
            boolean isDivisibleBy2 = isDivisible(numbers, number2);
            boolean isDivisibleBy3 = isDivisible(numbers, number3);

            if (isDivisibleBy2 || isDivisibleBy3) {
                System.out.println(numbers);
                count++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No divisor.");
            }

            numbers = numbers.add(increment);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isDivisible(BigDecimal number, BigDecimal divisor) {
        BigDecimal remainder = number.remainder(divisor);
        return remainder.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0;
    }
}

But this code goes in an infinite loop of priting "No divisor."
I think the problem is in isDivisible method, which checks divisibility by using the remainder method.
Any advice on my current approach would be appreciated.

How do you define divisibility on non-integers?

@Sören this is good point. What do we mean by divisibility on non-integers? Now that I think about it, i realize that misread the question. I think by "numbers with 50 decimal digits", the book meant "integers with 50 digits" and not "numbers with 50 digits after the decimal separator".

@Osmium Even if your algorithm would finish within the heat death of the universe (it won't - it's 1.4x10^51 operations), it will never give a result that's a non-integer. It prints 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14. It just does that extremely slowly. The remainder of dividing a decimal by an integer is never 0 (this part: remainder.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO))

Instead of jumping straight to coding without properly thinking about a problem, I should first take time in understanding the problem. Lesson learned.

I suggest that you want to use BigInteger, not BigDecimal.

numbers divisible by 2 - start with the smallest even one (e.g. 10000...00) and then add 2 in a loop; similar for divisible by 3, just the start number is a little bit more complicated (e.g. 10000...02) -- almost easier to do it on paper

@Michael why would you say that?  Forgetting the fact that this is extremely slow, numbers will eventually reach a decimal that's equal to an integer, in which case remainder.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) will indeed be 0.  The point of using compareTo instead of equals is that it ignores the scale, and just looks at the value of its operands.

@DawoodibnKareem "numbers will eventually reach a decimal that's equal to an integer" I know and I already said that. I said his algo prints 0, 2, 3, etc. (in theory, not in practice)

You don't have an infinite loop. Your increment is just so small that it just takes many, many, many iterations for the division to finally find a number that's divisible by 2 or 3. If I change the increment to 0.01 I get results almost immediately. With 0.00001 it takes seconds to find results. I don't know how long it takes to find the first result (2) with your increment, but it's not seconds, not even hours, and probably not even weeks - it could well be over a year. (The printing of the message doesn't help there either.)

It's 2e50 loops before numbers turns into 2.0 which is the first number for which the loop will exit. Assuming that it takes 1 second to find a result at .00001 (1e5), and given that this is an O(n) algorithm, we can linearly expand that time: It would take 2e50/1e5 = 63350000000000000000000000000000000 CENTURIES before this code would print. "it could well be over a year" you say. Um.. yeah. You slightly underestimated, there. The estimated heat death of the universe is ~1e100 years, so, I guess we can say: At least the universe itself doesn't literally stop you from doing this.

Wow, I was waaaaaaaay off ;)

I understand that the problem should be solved by writing a program, because that is what you want to practice …
But the approach to test the remainder of the division to be 0 is problematic when you look only for 2 and 3 as the divisors.
It is well known that each even number is divisible by 2, so you just need to test the last digit of a number to be even.
And a number is divisible by 3 when the sum of digits is divisible by three (or if it is 3, 6 or 9). Ok, we can discuss whether the division by 3 and checking the remainder is faster than getting the digits of the number and summing them up (repeatedly), and then checking if it is 3, 6 or 9.
The "brute force" method is only required for 7 as divisor (as long as we stay between 2 and 9).

These are points to consider. Thanks.
